# "I remember the day where" vs. "I remember the day when"

Tags: meaning, grammar, adverbs

What is the difference between "I remember the day where..." and "I remember the day when..."?

I think both are used in both written and spoken English. Can we say that "when" makes more sense when we are talking about a specific point in time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answerers suggested, *the day when* seems to be very common. In most cases both *the day when* and *the day where* refer to time, not place; but *the day where* is a bit archaic.

In my research, the only instance I found in which *the day where* refers to a place – not time – is in the book **The London Encyclopedia: or, Universal Dictionary of Science, Art, Literature, and Practical Mechanics. VOL. X. 1893**:

> To know by the globe what o clock it is in any part of the world at any time, provided you know the hour of **the day where you are at the same time**.

That said, it seems that other authors have used it by referring to a time not place. Here are just a few examples:

> Today might be **the day where** I could be the step in your swag the punctuation in your thoughts the why in your not the salt in your earth the light of your world . Today might be **the day where** I could be the silence in the midst of your storm...  – *The Color of My Aunt's Coffee: Sugar vs. Cream By Tia DeShay*
>
> I dream of **the day where** love will take my breath and carry me away . . . I dare to love a man as such the one, the true, the brave a soldier, Yes a soldier for my love – *Love Sick: Pages of a Poetic Heart
> By S. C. Ayala.*

Comment: This is the source of my confusion. I would like to speak/write a proper English, so I suppose I should stick to "when" ?

Comment: Yes, *when* seems to be the most common usage in most occasions.

Answer (score 4):

The King James Bible (Job, 3:3) has this: ‘Let the day perish **wherein** I was born, and the night in which it was said, There is a man child conceived.’ However, *the day when* is almost certainly what would be used on most occasions now. Do you have an authentic quotation showing *where* in such a context?

Answer (score 1):

I remember the place where...

And

I remember the day when...

are preferred.

I remember the day that...

is also possible because some people argue that the combination "day" and "when" is redundant.