# An era of intelligent machines where vs an era of intelligent machines when

Tags: when, where

I'm writing a essay and I haven't really studied or have had to use proper grammar in years now. For the following sentence:

We are now in a era of intelligent machines where Amazon has drones and Google has driverless cars....

Is the where correct? Or is it "when"? I think it is where, the where sounds much better. But technically era is a time, not a place? Should there be a comma after the where?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an error or just a typo, but it should be "an era," not "a era."

Comment: Ooh thanks for that link! And yes, it was just a typo. I was more careful in the actual essay :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The questions are deceivingly similar, but I don't think that the answer recommending _the moment that_ is appropriate here.

Comment: @200_success: You're quite right. I should have looked at the *answer*, not the *question*. I should have cited [*“I remember the day where” vs. “I remember the day when”*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74648/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of exactly what rules, but based on what "feels right" to me, I use:

- **era when** when I'm talking about an indeterminate time that is
  defined by what comes after the "when", and
- **era where** when I'm
  talking about a definite time that contains whatever features come
  after the "where".

For example:

> My parents lived in an era when newspapers reigned supreme.

My parents lived during some time period defined by when newspapers reigned supreme.

> My parents lived in an era where newspapers reigned supreme.

The era my parents lived in happened to have newspapers reigning supreme.

When using the present tense ("We live in an era..."), I always use "where" because I'm talking about a definite time (now).

Comment: Nice thanks! Yea the where feels right to me as well.